# Batch processing articles in database

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm upgrading a site to Joomla 3.3, and making some structural changes to the content. Currently, the article images are displayed inside the articles with normal `<img>` tags, but I'd like to change to using the intro- and full-image settings in each article.

Is it possible to somehow extract the images from the articles and place them in the correct fields by quering the database (or maybe there is an extension for this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only developing a custom script.

You can only know the general internal article structure (... the exceptions), instantiate the DOM tree, re-organize and save the new article.